# Verify that all text input fields are empty with Selenium

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to verify that all input text fields are empty with Selenium IDE/Webdriver. Suppose if there is a method that can return all HTML input elements with the attribute "text" or "textarea", then I could iterate over all of them and check if the text context is empty.

But I cannot find such a method. What  other ways can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Consider that .text will not work on input fields and you MUST get the value attribute.

```
bool areAllFieldsClear()
{
    var myFields = driver.FindElements(By.Xpath("//input"));
    foreach(var field in myFields)
    {
       if(field.GetAttribute("value") != "") {
           return false;  //field.Clear(); maybe?
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for being late to the game.  Came across this looking for something else.

Comment: I got it when changed **if** condition like this `if(field.getAttribute("value").isEmpty())`. The `!=null` or `!=""` conditions were not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I do it.  I catch all of the inputs text and textarea and password in some cases and store those elements in a list of IWebElements.  Then I can iterate through the list and verify whatever I want.

```
private List<IWebElement> GetTextFields(IWebDriver driver)
{

 List<IWebElement> textFields;

 try{
  textFields.AddRange(driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("input[type='text']").ToList());
 }
 catch {
  //throw exception or log exception
 }

 try {
  textFields.AddRange(driver.FindElements(By.TagName("textarea").ToList());
 }
 catch {
  //throw exception or log exception
 }

textFields.RemoveRange(i => !i.Displayed); //removes all hidden fields

return textFields
}
```

here's how you can verify no text with that list.

```
foreach(IWebElement element in textFields)
{
 if(element.text != "")
 {
  //log error or throw exception
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

did u tried.

```
driver.findElements(By)
```

This will give you a list of all webelements available on the page using the locator u specified.